# i want to change text of first div id="Comment_1" using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<div id="Comment_1" class="panel-body">Back when I was in high school
  <div><a href="#">Ajay</a>(725) <span class="sl-date">7/28/2016 2:48:37 PM</span>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-footer">
    <a class="btnDisapproveComment btn btn-outline m-r-10 btn-danger" action="Disapprove" iid="1" href="javascript:void(0)">Disapprove</a>
    <a class="btnEditComment btn btn-outline m-r-10 btn-warning" iid="1" href="javascript:void(0)">Edit</a>
    <a class="btnFlagComment btn btn-outline m-r-10 btn-default " iid="1" href="javascript:void(0)">Flag it</a>
    <a class="btnAllActionComment btn btn-outline m-r-10 btn-info" action="Feature" iid="1" href="javascript:void(0)">Feature it</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: damn, now it looks different

Comment: @ArunPJohny – What made you think that way ? All about experience huh!

Comment: @Rayon at least doesn't look right a out right spam

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you want to change "Back when I was in high school" only.

If so add span for the same, like., `<span class="span-text-to-replace">Back when I was in high school</span>`

Then,

```
$(".span-text-to-replace").text("My new text");
```

In case you don't want to add any span/div, you could do this,

```
document.getElementById("Comment_1").childNodes[0].textContent = "My new text"
```

The above line changes the content.

Hope I answered your question!

Comment: i want to change this text --> Back when I was in high school

Comment: My answer is applicable for you... Try and let me know if you face any issues... Just add a span to the text and replace the content with the $.text() method

Comment: thank @yuva $(".span-text-to-replace").text("My new text") working.

Answer (score 0):

> Use [**`NodechildNodes`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) property which will return all the child nodes including `TextNodes`

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('Comment_1');
elem.childNodes[0].textContent = "Your Text"
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Comment_1" class="panel-body">Back when I was in high school
  <div><a href="#">Ajay</a>(725) <span class="sl-date">7/28/2016 2:48:37 PM</span>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-footer">
    <a class="btnDisapproveComment btn btn-outline m-r-10 btn-danger" action="Disapprove" iid="1" href="javascript:void(0)">Disapprove</a>
    <a class="btnEditComment btn btn-outline m-r-10 btn-warning" iid="1" href="javascript:void(0)">Edit</a>
    <a class="btnFlagComment btn btn-outline m-r-10 btn-default " iid="1" href="javascript:void(0)">Flag it</a>
    <a class="btnAllActionComment btn btn-outline m-r-10 btn-info" action="Feature" iid="1" href="javascript:void(0)">Feature it</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following if you want to change the text in that div

```
$('#Comment_1').text('I am to lazy to search the www for a simple tutorial on appending a text to a div');
```